# Localize error 500 page in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling, custom-error-pages

I've been going through stack overflow but cannot find an answer to this. I can get the 500 page to show up ok like this:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="500"
         redirect="~/500.html"/>
</customErrors>
```

What I would like to do is to present a localized version of the page based on the app language. Problem is that I would not like to go through the Error Controller-View solution that I found in lots of other posts, in case there is an actual error in the App (missing DLLs etc.). So I have to serve a pure html page, but I need to be able to choose the localized one, or instruct IIS on how to find it.

Any idea?

Comment: You do that through Application_Error

Comment: Nope, I can't... or at least, I can but I wanted to avoid anything that involved C# code and know if it was possible to solve from the web.config

Answer (score 0):

This is just off the top of my head, couldn't you use URL rewrite/redirect rules that use the Accept-Language that the browser defines to redirect to ~/500.en-us.html and ~/500.de.html or however you may have the pathing setup?

Example Rule in web.config:

```
<rule name="HTTP-Language-Error-Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^500.html$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE}" pattern="^([a-z]{1,8}(-[a-z]{1,8})?)\s*(;\s*q\s*=\s*(1|0\.[0-9]+))?$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="500.{C:1}.html" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

My thinking is that the redwrite/redirect rule would work as it's part of IIS's processes handling the request and not the app code. So it could still work, theoretically, if the WebApp is broken for some reason. I could be totally wrong in my assumption though, and I thought I'd give it an honest shot.